# Can I fill space in junction box wire clamp?

Tags: electrical

After removing some unneeded circuits from a subpanel the wires are not as tightly clamped at the box entry as I would like.

They're not loose, but I would prefer zero wiggles.

Is there an approved way I can fill space in the existing clamp or must I remove everything and replace it with a smaller clamp + reducer?

Comment: What sort of clamp is it that doesn't sufficiently close?

Comment: What type of cables are being clamped in these clamps, for that matter?

Comment: These are NM cables. I removed a 8/2 because I eliminated a set of wall ovens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on cable abandonment code, but I'd fold a short length of the same type of cable over and slip it through the clamp, leaving the cut ends inside the panel box. This leaves you with a tidy flattened loop outside. It could be barely long enough to protrude from the clamp on both sides, rendering it almost invisible.

Comment: This is an easy solution but are there any regulatory problems with looping unused cable back into panel?

Comment: I'd expect some of our resident sparkies will fill us in on that. Feel free to leave the question open. I'm curious, too.